# regex pattern to permit special character at alternative position only

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to build a regex which will permit special characters only at alternative positions. For example, `A:)B` is not permitted but `A:B` is permitted.

`A:B:C` is permitted but `A,!@B*(C((D` is not.

The only requirement is to allow special characters at alternative position even a special character followed by number/character is permitted.

No two special characters can be together regardless of them being same or different and even two consecutive alphanumerics should be permitted.

Comment: You can try something here http://regexr.com/ for testing

Comment: This question needs work to be answerable. You need to define special characters and "normal" characters (only uppercase ASCII letters?). Would `:A)B$` be allowed? Etc., the rules for matching are as yet unclear.

Comment: every thing else is permitted apart from two different or same special characters today

Comment: Try [this Java demo](http://ideone.com/41FBrT), see [the  regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CBsbG9/1/).

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for your case:

```
[0-9A-Za-z]+([~`!@#$%^&*()_+\-=;':"][0-9A-Za-z]+)+
```

I have tested some cases on [regexr](http://regexr.com/3g1h5):

*PS: I am not `\w` and `\W` as `_` is interpreted as being part of `\w`. In this case I'm assuming `_` will be a special character.*

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: It is not matching `A#B@#C`, what is the problem that you see?

Comment: A#B@#C this is matched where as even this should not be matched since two special characters are together

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
  String test="A@@B";
  String test1="A@B;)B";
  String PWD_REGEX="[0-9A-Za-z]+([~`!@#$%^&*()_+\\-=;':\"][0-9A-Za-z]+)+";
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(PWD_REGEX);
  if (pattern.matcher(test1).find())
  {
   System.out.println("matches");
  }
  System.out.println("end");
 }
i wrote this program and both the syso get printed

Comment: There is a problem with the regex in YOUR code. There are non-printable characters between ]+ in the snippet you put above. DELETE them and re-paste the regex from the answer above. It works!

Comment: See here : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMSE9peHZUb1pvZ2M ... Remove the invalid line and run it.